# Why is my doubly linked list remove function deleting multiple nodes?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am writing the code in C++ for a doubly linked list. I'm a beginner to C++ so forgive me for asking this. I am populating the doubly linked list with numbers (1,2,3,...,n). I use the search function first and find the node that contains the value I want to remove. Then I call the remove function in order to remove the node. My remove function seems to be removing more than just one node and I have been wracking my head trying to figure it out. I think it might be because my DList class does not have a destructor but I'm not sure how to implement that as the structure I'm trying to delete is a ListNode. Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you.

eg. test case n = 8

list before deletion: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

list after deletion: 7

**DLIST.H**

```
#ifndef DLIST_H
#define DLIST_H

struct ListNode 
{
  /* define your list node type */
  int val;
  ListNode* next;
  ListNode* prev;
};

class DList
{
  public:
  DList();
  /* implement copy constructor, assignment, destructor if needed */
  void add_to_front(int value);
  void add_to_back(int value);
  int first();
  int last();
  void remove(ListNode* node);
  void display();
  ListNode* previous(ListNode* node);
  ListNode* next(ListNode* node);
  ListNode* search_value(int value);

  private:
  /* declare your data */
  ListNode* head;
  ListNode* tail;
};

#endif
```

**DLIST.CC**

```
#include "dlist.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

      //ListNode* head;
      //ListNode* tail;

      DList::DList(){
         head = NULL;
         tail = NULL;
      }

      void DList::add_to_front(int value){ 
         if (head != NULL){
            //std::cout<<"addfront1\n";
            ListNode *newhead = new ListNode();
            newhead->val = value;
            //std::cout<<"addfront1 val" << newhead->val << "\n";
            newhead->next = head;
            newhead->prev = NULL;
            head->prev = newhead;
            head = newhead;
         }else{
            //std::cout<<"addfront2\n";
            ListNode *newhead = new ListNode();
            newhead->val  = value; 
            //std::cout<<"addfront2 val" << newhead->val << "\n";
            newhead->prev = NULL; 
            newhead->next = NULL;
            head = newhead;   
            tail = newhead;
         }
      }    

      void DList::add_to_back(int value){
         if (tail != NULL){
            //std::cout<<"addback1\n";
            ListNode *newtail = new ListNode();
            newtail->val = value;
            //std::cout<<"addback1 val" << newtail->val << "\n";
            newtail->next = NULL;
            newtail->prev = tail;
            tail->next = newtail;
            tail = newtail;
         }else{
            //std::cout<<"addback2\n";
            ListNode *newtail = new ListNode();
            newtail->val = value;
            //std::cout<<"addback2 val" << newtail->val << "\n";
            newtail->prev = NULL;
            newtail->next = NULL;
            tail = newtail;
            head = newtail;
         }
      }

      int DList::first(){
         return head->val;
      }

      int DList::last(){
         return tail->val;
      }

      void DList::remove(ListNode* node){

         std::cout << "want to del value is " << node->val  << "\n";
         ListNode *toDelete = new ListNode();
         if (head == NULL || tail == NULL){
            return;
         }

         if(head->val == node->val){
            toDelete = head;
            head = node->next;
            if (head != NULL){
               head->prev = NULL;
            }
            std::cout << "del1 value is " << toDelete->val  << "\n";
            delete(toDelete);
         }else if(tail->val == node->val){
            toDelete = tail;
            tail = node->prev;
            std::cout << "del2 newtail value is " << node->prev->val  << "\n";
            if (tail != NULL){
               tail->next = NULL;
            }
            std::cout << "del2 value is " << toDelete->val  << "\n";
            delete(toDelete);
         }else if (node != NULL){
            std::cout << "node1 value is " << node->val  << "\n";
            node->prev->next = node->next;
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
            std::cout << "node2 value is " << node->val  << "\n";
            delete(node);
         }
      }

      ListNode* DList::previous(ListNode* node){
         if(node->prev != NULL){
            return node->prev;
         }else{
            return node;
         }
      }

      ListNode* DList::next(ListNode* node){
         if(node->next != NULL){
            return node->next;
         }else{
            return node;
         }
      }

      ListNode* DList::search_value(int value){
         //std::cout << "head.0\n";
         //std::cout << "head value is " << head->val  << "\n";
         while(head->next != NULL){
            //std::cout << "head.1\n";
            if(head->next->val == value){
               //std::cout << "head.2\n";
               return head->next;
            }else{
               //std::cout << "head.3\n";
               head = head->next;
            }
         }
         if (head->next == NULL){
            if (head->val == value){
               return head;
            }else{
               //std::cout << "error\n";
            }
         }

      }

      void DList::display(){
         std::cout<<"Element In The Linked List Are : ";
         ListNode *disp= new ListNode;
         disp = head;
         while(disp!=NULL)
         {
             std::cout<<" "<<disp->val;
             if(disp->next==NULL)
             {
                 std::cout<<"\n";
                 break;
             }
             disp=disp->next;
         }
      }
```

**DLIST_TEST.CC**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "dlist.h"
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int N = -1;
  if (argc == 2) {
    N = atoi (argv[1]);
    assert (N > 0);
  } 
  //cout << "N is " << N << "\n";
  DList testList = DList();
  int i = 0;
  while(i<N){
    //cout << "i value is "<< i << "\n";
    testList.add_to_back(i+1);
    //cout << "second\n";
    i++;
  }
  int randn = rand() % N + 1;// randn in the range 1 to N
  cout << "randn is "<< randn <<"\n";
  testList.display();
  clock_t t1,t2;
  t1=clock();

  ListNode* loc = testList.search_value(randn);
  cout << "loc value is "<< loc->val <<"\n";
  testList.remove(loc);

  t2=clock();

  float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
  float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout<<"\nTime taken by function: "<<seconds<<" seconds\n" << endl;  

  testList.display();
  testList.add_to_front(N);
  testList.display();


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: First mistake: `ListNode *toDelete = new ListNode();` has no business being in a "remove" function, especially since it is the start of what ultimately becomes a memory leak.

Comment: The same `ListNode *disp= new ListNode;` bug is in `display()`.

Comment: When the `node` to remove is in the middle of the list but it happens to have the same value as the head or the tail node, your `remove()` will delete the wrong node from the list. That's another bug you will have to fix. And to figure out the reason for your bug, you need to use a debugger. Have you used a debugger, yet, to debug your program, and if not why not?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, The values inserted into the list are incremented (1,2,3,....,n) so I did not feel the need to check for duplicates as no two nodes will have the same value. I'm not really certain of debuggers as I have no experience with them really but I figure that would be the next step for me to learn.

Comment: @WhozCraig, my understanding was that toDelete created in the function would only last the lifetime of the function, and thus would not be a problem when the function call ends. Is this not the case?

Comment: @NicholasChiu Anything created with `new` is on the heap, not the stack, and thus lives until it is killed, not until the scope ends. You might want to read into the topic of heap and stack. One essential thing: every `new` needs a matching `delete`.

Comment: You are correct, this is, indeed, the next step for you to learn. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you will be able to find and fix bugs without asking anyone for help. Doesn't that make much more sense, then waiting days for someone to see your question on some website?

Answer (score 0):

I got some good tips about other things, but I found that in my search_value function, I was actually modifying the head using the member function. Using a temporary head to return the location of the node instead, the node was correctly deleted later.